# How to prove: $\sqrt{\tan{a}\tan{b}} ≤ \tan{\frac{a+b}2} ≤ \frac{1}{2}(\tan{a}+\tan{b})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Suppose that $0≤a≤b<\frac{π}{4}$

Show that $\sqrt{\tan{a}\tan{b}}≤\tan{\frac{a+b}{2}}≤\frac{1}{2}(\tan{a}+\tan{b})$.

I want to prove this inequality without using calculus.

So, I tried the following: let $\tan{\frac{a}{2}}=x$ and $\tan{\frac{b}{2}}=y$.

Then, using the basic formulas related to the trigonometric functions, I got

$2\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}} \le \frac{x+y}{1-xy} \le \frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{y}{1-y^2}$.

However, I couldn't advance any further.

Although I know the second part of the inequality can be easily proved by using

Jensen's inequality and the convexity of the tangent function on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$,

I was not able to prove the convexity of the tangent function without using calculus.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In order for your question to make sense, you should make sure to check that the "basic formulas related to trigonometric functions" do not rely on / can be proven without using convexity of $\sin, \cos, $ or $\tan.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $2\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}} ≤ \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$

Square and simplify it, we convert it to

$$\frac{(1-xy)^2-(x+y)^2}{(1 - x^2) (1 - x y)^2 (1 - y^2)}\ge0\Leftrightarrow (1-xy)\ge(x+y)\Leftrightarrow \frac{x+y}{1-xy}\le1$$

This is true, because

$$\frac{x+y}{1-xy}=\tan\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\le\tan\frac{\pi}4=1$$

> $\frac{x+y}{1-xy} ≤ \frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{y}{1-y^2}$

Simplify and we get:

$$\frac{(x - y)^2 (x + y)}{(1 - x^2) (1 - x y) (1 - y^2)}\ge0$$

This is obviously true. So we are done.